# Comparing characters of a string

Tags: c, string

How to compare each character of a string using `if` , `string[i]` (`i` is a number of a sequence of hat string). The idea of the program is to give values to letters like a=1, b=2 and if i write a word in console ("a,b,a,b"), I'd get the sum of 1+2+1+2. 
I want to compare each character of the string until the end of the string. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h >


int main ()
{
    char string1[20];


    char a='a', b='b', g='g', X='X', i='i', H='H', V='V', d='d', e='e', v='v', z='z', E='E', T='T', I='I', k='k', l='l', m='m', n='n', o='o', p='p', j='j', r='r', s='s', t='t', u='u', f='f', q='q', R='R', y='y', S='S', w='w', C='C', W='W', x='x', h='h', c='c', J='J', Z='Z';




    int rigi;
    int sum;

    printf (" my word is:\n");
    scanf( "%19s ", string1);



     sum=0;
       for (rigi = 0; string1[rigi] !='\0'; rigi++)
    {

    if (string1[rigi]==a ) {sum= sum +1;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==b ) {sum= sum +2;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==g ) {sum= sum +3;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==d ) {sum= sum +4;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==e ) {sum= sum +5;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==v ) {sum= sum +6;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==z ) {sum= sum +7;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==E ) {sum= sum +8;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==T ) {sum= sum +9;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==i ) {sum= sum +10;} else 
    if (string1[rigi]==k ) {sum= sum +20;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==l ) {sum= sum +30;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==m ) {sum= sum +40;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==n ) {sum= sum +50;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==I ) {sum= sum +60;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==o ) {sum= sum +70;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==p ) {sum= sum +80;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==J ) {sum= sum +90;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==r ) {sum= sum +100;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==s ) {sum= sum +200;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==t ) {sum= sum +300;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==V ) {sum= sum +400;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==u ) {sum= sum +0;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==f ) {sum= sum +500;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==q ) {sum= sum +600;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==R ) {sum= sum +700;} else 
    if (string1[rigi]==y ) {sum= sum +800;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==S ) {sum= sum +900;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==C ) {sum= sum +1000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==c ) {sum= sum +2000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==Z ) {sum= sum +3000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==w ) {sum= sum +4000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==W ) {sum= sum +5000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==x ) {sum= sum +6000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==X ) {sum= sum +7000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==j ) {sum= sum +8000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==h ) {sum= sum +9000;} else
    if (string1[rigi]==H ) {sum= sum +1000;} else
    {sum=0;}

       }

    printf ("%d\n" , sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `P.S i used spaces in some places [i know]` -> eh, you posted code that is uncompilable and unreadable by intent?!

Comment: Explain sum 1=1; and sum 2=2;

Comment: The code has more warnings and errors than lines of code :)

Comment: sum 1 is just a value i give to a character

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze, you can edit your post, and repair it. In it's current shape, nobody will even try to help you.

Comment: Paste your compilable code here. where is the declaration of string1 and sum1

Comment: i tried to find the button of edit but ... ill try :S

Comment: `char string[20];` is declaration of variable named 'string', which is array of 20 characters. (for example)

Comment: i edited the code it works now as i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to intialize variables `a` and `b`.
I think like this

```
char a='a', b='b';
```

Check this code. I think this is what you need

```
int main ()
{
    char string[20];
    char a='a', b='b';
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf (" my word is:\n");
    scanf ( "%s", string);

    for (i = 0; string[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (string[i]==a ) 
        {            
             sum= sum + 1;
        } 
        else if (string[i]==b ) 
        {
             sum= sum + 2;
        }
    }
    printf ("%d\n" , sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: debug error!
run-time check failed #3-the variable "i" is being used without being initialized. this is the CRASH ERROR

Comment: wow this is better than mine thank u ill try ))))

Comment: Yea read the error and look into your code. You are not intialising variables a, b, i etc in your code. For accessing first element i should be equal to zero. For comparing a variable a for value 'a' you should intialise with 'a'

Comment: Ok. Please understand it before copying it

Comment: i did, and this is exactly the thing i wanted

Comment: what if I gave the input aatish. It would not work if the input character is other than a or b. Using this method to work from a to z would be hideous. Why not look at mine solution @555k [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764377/comparing-characters-of-a-string/15765148#15765148)

Comment: but here is no "answer my question bar"..

Comment: i will edit my question and put the answer instead

Comment: i simulated Georgian  letters 38 in total

Comment: I think you have new thread for ypur new spacebar check problem. If thats the only issue i will answer there.

Comment: i have a problem here. code works but i need to optimize it. the thing doesn't work as i want is that i after space bar i need to add at least one more symbol to make it calculate...
ex:
when i write in console "asd" it cant work like waiting for something more. but if i write "asd f" (i mean one letter or a word after space bar it  will calculate. but if i want to add a loop like WHILE or  FOR it cant calculate right answer because the program starts calculating that "f"which i wrote after space bar before... Plus i'm banned i cant ask any question anymore. *hope someone will see soon*

Comment: Remove space in scanf

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this. `toascii()` function included in header file `ctype.h` it basically converts the character to its ASCII value but since the ascii of a is 97 we can substract 96 and get a as 1, b as 2, an so on. If u want you can check wheather the character is capital or small letter and make it advanced. But for now i have included a simple on for small letter only. Hope you got your answer.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<string.h>
    main()
    {
     int i,value = 0;
     char string[10];
     printf("Enter a word");
     scanf("%s",string);
         for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
     {
    value = value + (toascii(string[i]) - 96);
     }

      printf("the sum is = %d",value);
     }
```

Is this what you are trying to do??
You could click the tick mark if its what you wanted.

Comment: this is hard. im just a beginner :(

Comment: just try copying and running it and look at each line if any problem we are here

Comment: i have learned only <stdio.h>, i cant understand the operation toascii() but ill try to run if i get the thing i want

Comment: haha this works!!! but i don know how yet... :( but i hope ill learn soon. thank u guys )))

Comment: you can still approve my ans (accept my answer) the thing is every character has its ascii value e.g. `A = 65` `a = 97` and `toascii()` does the converting thing and what we have to do is simply modify and use in our own way as per the need

Comment: but what if i would give value 99 to a and 100 to b? this is the thing im trying to (to give special numerical values to  letters). if i could chose yours and the upper one in the sam time id do that with pleasure but  i could mark only one. im sorry but the answer upper of this comment is lil bit better for me beginner :(

Comment: its simple if you want to give value 99 to a and so on just change the  code inside the for loop and type `value = value + (toascii(string[i]) +2);` Just have a look of it works and notify me..

Comment: ur code works but i needed this
a=1
b=2
...
j=10
k=20
l=30
...
s=100
t=200
etc.

Comment: If you want to do that mine would not work but using the code you accepted as an ans you would have to write if statement for all the values you want to assign and that would be a crap code. Better use the code which is short and does the work fine why go for a long hideous way.

Comment: i wrote if statements 33 times 
))) to calculate for Georgian alfabet )))

Comment: but still it doesnt work as i want ((( i cant terminate when i want to, i write space bar and it needs one more letter to terminate after pressing ENTER